# Outlet collection with NSArray to singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, singleton, iboutletcollection

I have a sequencer with each track that has buttons as an outlet collection. The code all works fine in it's own view controller however I want to transfer all the methods to a singleton so that I can control the playback from other views.

for instance I have

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *trackOneOutletCollection;
```

However I have methods which act on the alpha and tags of each button; the methods contain these vales which I don't know how to access from the singleton. I thought the singleton was where I store all the data and then call it from the class file view controller?

Comment: You shouldn't connect the buttons directly to the singleton.  The buttons in the view controller should trigger code in the view controller that calls the appropriate methods on your player singleton (play/pause, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inheritance concept to achieve this functionality.you  need to create one `ParentViewController` that hold `IBOutletCollection` property. and rest of all View Controller is child of `ParentViewController`. then you can access `IBOutletCollection` in other view ontroller. like this way.

**ParentViewController:-**

```
@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *trackOneOutletCollection;

@end
```

**ChildViewController;-**

```
@interface YourViewController : ParentViewController

@end
```

**.m file**

```
@implementation YourViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"trackOneOutletCollection = %@"self.trackOneOutletCollection);
}
@end
```

Comment: I already have this setup, however in the parent view controller I have the playback buttons and in the child view controller, I have the sequencer buttons